# How to add overflow menu to Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-appcompat

I'm trying to use Android `ActionBar` in my app, and have an option that's hidden away in the overflow menu.

There's a lot of documentation out there, but it's confusing because most of it is only relevant to very old versions of Android, and when you try applying the same concepts, they don't work anymore or work differently.

This is in my `Activity` layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

And this is in my `Activity`'s `onCreate()` method

```
// sets up activity toolbar
Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

myToolbar.showOverflowMenu();
myToolbar.setTitleTextColor(R.color.lightPrimaryText);
```

I've also tried inflating a menu xml file from the `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, but that also didn't give me the results I wanted.

Comment: add this line to your style you're using `<item name="colorControlNormal">#fff</item>`

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Define a `Menu` for your `Toolbar` in the *res/menu* resource folder, for example:

*toolbar_menu.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_sign_out"
        android:title="@string/toolbar_sign_out"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

Setting `app:showAsAction="never"` ensures that this `MenuItem` will not be shown in the `Toolbar`, but placed in the overflow menu instead.

The theme of your `Activity` should be (or derive from) one of the `NoActionBar` themes (`Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` for example, or `Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar` if you're using [Material Components](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/)).

In your `Activity`, set up your `Toolbar`:

```
Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
```

And override `onCreateOptionsMenu()` to inflate your previously defined menu resource:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

You can override `onOptionsItemSelected()` to define the onClick behaviour of your `MenuItem`(s):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_sign_out: {
            // do your sign-out stuff
            break;
        }
        // case blocks for other MenuItems (if any)
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

in manifest file declare

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

like this :

```
<activity
    android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/label"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

and add this to your style :

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

and call this in Activity onCreate() :

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

override this method in activity:

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.product_list, menu);
    //U can find item set icon and stuff...
    MenuItem item= menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

    return true;
}
```

and declare your menu like this for overflow menu:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu >
    <group>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/sign_out"
            android:title="@string/sign_out" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/about"
            android:title="@string/about" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

and for handle item selection call this

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) { 
       case R.id.sign_out:
       //do stuff
           break;
           }  
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

done :)

Answer (score -1):

Simple do This copy this code on your MainActivet`

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main2, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Group gp=(Group)findViewById(R.id.order);

            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }`
```

Now Make Directory file for menu name for this go on Android_Studio->app Folder->Right_Click->New->Directory-> Enter name menu    now Create a xml file in there with menu2.xml name

and past this code on menu2.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        />

</menu>
```

if any Query Please text me